# wrile sql query using group

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: tables Employee, Department]

Нужно получить e.name, e.salary c максимальной зарплатой для каждого департамента, используя в запросе команды 'group' и может быть 'having'

есть рабочий запрос, но как написать альтернативный запрос не знаю

```
select e.name, e.salary  from employee e 
where salary = (select max(salary) from employee e2 
                where e.department_id = e2.department_id)
```

Comment: *как написать альтернативный запрос не знаю* RANK() в CTE, в основном запросе выбор только тех записей, где значение равно единице. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

```
select
  e.name
  ,e.salary
from employee e
where e.salary in
  (select max(salary) as s
   from employee e
   group by e.department_id)
```

но если уж так надо приплести having, то можно построить что-то вроде этого, но зачем это нужно, я не понимаю

```
select
  e.name
  ,e.salary
from employee e
join (
  select 
    max(e.salary) as salary 
    , e.department_id
  from employee e
  group by e.department_id
  having max(e.salary) in 
  (select max(salary) as s
   from employee e
   group by e.department_id)
) s 
on s.salary = e.salary
```

тестировал тут: [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/08f8c/5)